# how to convert total number of hosts in network to mask?

Tags: bash, shell, networking

how can i convert the total number of hosts in a network to mask?

for example, `1024` to `/22`

`ip calc` can do the opposite

```
$ ipcalc 89.150.4.0/22

Address:   89.150.4.0           01011001.10010110.000001 00.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.252.0 = 22   11111111.11111111.111111 00.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.3.255            00000000.00000000.000000 11.11111111
=>
Network:   89.150.4.0/22        01011001.10010110.000001 00.00000000
HostMin:   89.150.4.1           01011001.10010110.000001 00.00000001
HostMax:   89.150.7.254         01011001.10010110.000001 11.11111110
Broadcast: 89.150.7.255         01011001.10010110.000001 11.11111111
Hosts/Net: 1022                 Class A
```

---

background information:

i have a text file with content like

```
AD|85.94.160.0|8192
AD|89.150.2.0|512
AD|89.150.4.0|1024
AD|89.150.8.0|2048
```

and i need to convert the 3rd column (total number of hosts) to network mask

if it's not possible using shell tools, i don't mind piping it to a python/perl/ruby script

---

EDIT

very concise answer and comments from @KamilCuk helped me understand the logic behind it.
i'm not even using `ipcalc` for that anymore :)

THE ANSWER

**from `hosts` to `mask`**

```
$: HOSTS=1024
$: LC_NUMERIC=C printf "%.0f" $(bc -l <<< "32-(l($HOSTS)/l(2))")

22
```

or

```
$: HOSTS=1024
$: echo | awk -v HOSTS=$HOSTS '{print int(32-(log(HOSTS)/log(2)))}'

22
```

**and from `mask` to `hosts`**

```
$: MASK=22
$: echo "2^(32-$MASK)" | bc

1024
```

or

```
$: MASK=22
$: echo | awk -v MASK=$MASK '{print 2^(32-MASK)}'

1024
```

Comment: There is a section in [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) called _Subnet Sizing Based on Number of Hosts
_ that explains how to calculate the network mask based on the number of hosts. Other sections are helpful because you can generate a host mask and change it to a mask length.

Comment: What would be the output for the presented input?

Comment: @KamilCuk `AD|89.150.4.0|1024` -> `AD|89.150.4.0/22`

Comment: What it explains is the algorithm of how to arrive at the mask.

Comment: @RASG, that is not actually the number of hosts on the network it is the total number of addresses on the network. For 1024 usable host addresses, it is `/21`.

Comment: `ip calc can do the opposite` Just `2^(32-22)`....

Comment: @KamilCuk so what you're saying is that i dont need `ipcalc` at all. just `2^(32-mask)`

Comment: Yes. Maybe a good read about what a mask is and what it represents would be advisable. In shell just `echo '2^(32-$mask)' | bc` or with `awk -vmask=$mask '{print 2^(32-mask}'` etc.

Comment: @RonMaupin i need total number of addresses. will edit to make it more clear. thanks

Comment: If you really want to do this type of thing. I really recommend reading and understanding the whole answer I linked. It explains how to arrive at all the types of questions when it comes to IPv4 addressing and subnetting.

Comment: @RonMaupin already reading it. thanks for the link. but i got to admit that KamilCuk answer and comments are perfect. very concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate in `bc` or `awk` the logarithm. Then just substract from 32.

For your input file that would be:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $2"/"32 - log($3)/log(2)}'
```

Comment: That depends on if it is the total number of addresses, or the number of usable addresses. For example, 512 total addresses is `/23`, but for usable addresses, it is `/22`.

Comment: @RonMaupin total addresses

Comment: @RASG, the question asks for the number of hosts, which would be the number of usable addresses, not the total number of addresses. That is often the trick in the question. That is explained in the section to which I referred.